# Very simple pygame window lags a lot

Tags: python, pygame, lag

I've got a problem with pygame, I've only added a background image and an icon to the window but its lagging whenever I run it and I have no clue why, I've added the convert function but it did not help.

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# generate game window
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Under Attack")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
# import background
background = pygame.image.load('assets/resize.jpg').convert()
icon=pygame.image.load('assets/alienicon.png').convert()

running = True

# loop that will execute while the condition is true
while running:
    # apply background to the window
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    #apply icon to window
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    # update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # if the gamer closes the window
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # check if event is event of closing window
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
        print("Quitting the game...")
```

[image]

Comment: 'lags' = window or entire pc becomes sluggish? The while loop is hoggin all available resources. I guess you have an indentation problem. Try indenting the whole `for event in pygame.event.get():` and all it contains so that it is part of `while running`. A event loop usually needs a sleeper operation which I assume is what `pygame.event.get()` is for

Comment: @gnight its just the window that lags and okay ill try that

Comment: @gnight after fixing the indentation problem it doesnt seem to be lagging now, thank you(:

Comment: added solution as answer so the question doesn't look like an orphan

Comment: You probably don't need to re-set the icon every time through the loop, either.

Answer (score 2):

'lags' = window becomes sluggish? The while loop is hogging all available resources.

You have an indentation problem. Try indenting the whole `for event in pygame.event.get():` and all it contains so that it is part of `while running`.

A event loop usually needs a sleeper operation which is what `pygame.event.get()` is for.

```
while running:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            print("Quitting the game...")
```